# SQLite working on Unity Editor but not in Android device

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I cannot access my sqlite database in my android device but it is working perfectly well in the unity editor. I've tried changing the `dataPath` to `persistentDataPath` but still didn't work. I also followed this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html, and still can't access my DB in my phone. What is the solution?

Comment: check here https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-3d-android-sqlite-examples.114660/

Comment: still not working :(